# ini_set not working in session upload php

Tags: php

I am trying to set php.ini from php file,
I am trying to run the following code
Without success :

```
<?php
ini_set('session.upload_progress.prefix', 'my_progress_id_');
echo ini_get('session.upload_progress.prefix');
?>
```

The code I get is remaining :
**upload_progress_**

what could be the problem

Comment: "The best way to check if [ini_set] works is to first check the disable_functions flag in php.ini to see if it is disabled, and then (if it is not disabled), change a value with it, and echo phpinfo() immediately after. If the value is changed under the local column, then you know ini_set works."
https://stackoverflow.com/a/251536/1983827

Comment: i try  ini_set('disable_functions', 'On'); but this not work

Comment: if i use print_r(ini_get_all()); [disable_functions] => Array ([local_value] => is empty

Answer (score 0):

If you cross reference the various manual pages - http://php.net/manual/en/ini.list.php which shows that `session.upload_progress.prefix` is settable as `PHP_INI_PERDIR`.

`PHP_INI_PERDIR` from http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.modes.php...

> PHP_INI_PERDIR    Entry can be set in php.ini, .htaccess, httpd.conf or
>   .user.ini (since PHP 5.3)

So this particular setting can't be changed by `ini_set()`.

Comment: i use .htaccess : php_value  session.upload_progress.prefix  upload_progress_id_ and its work Thanks  :)

Comment: OK - if this answered has helped, please consider marking it as answered.